# Featured Image Link

Tags: feature-request, featured-photo

I love the featured image, and I think it's great to link to the user's page and the next week's vote.  However, there have been a couple of times when I wanted to look at the photo in greater detail.  I had to go to the meta and find the vote page for the week, then grab the flickr link from the answer.  Wouldn't it make sense to have a link to flickr from the featured image on the main site?  Or at least a "See other entries" (or something) link that links to the previous vote?

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't always be possible, as submitted entries are restricted to be exactly that size. Where I see an image is also hosted on Flickr, I tend to click through and invite all entries to be added to the [Photo.StackExchange](http://www.flickr.com/groups/1585269@N22/) group. You may find that an easier way of navigating some of the various entries.

Of course, not everybody wants to use Flickr (I'd be surprised if the SmugMug folk did, for example).

Comment: Perhaps a link to the SmugMug page, in that case?  I'm not necessarily concerned with Flickr specifically, just a way to see a nice picture in better detail.  As I said, perhaps there could be a link to the post/answer containing that picture.

Comment: I'm not aware of a SmugMug group for this site *yet* - I was referring to the number of SmugMug staff that have contributed some great answers on here, rather than a group on there...

Comment: I wasn't referring to a SmugMug group -- instead, I was suggesting a link to the photo on SmugMug, Flickr, personal site, wherever the image comes from.

Comment: Could we simply start the convention of when folks submit a photo, also submit a URL that's a link to that photo elsewhere/bigger?  Then it wouldn't matter if it was on Flickr, SmugMug, Picasa, or anywhere else...

Comment: @ahockley Without checking the stats, I have the perception that *most* entries already do; I understood Nick was suggesting making that link more obvious somehow? Either way, when it comes to next week's post, I'll try to remember to explicitly mention it (there are technical reasons why I don't want to do it to this weeks)

Comment: @Rowland Yep, I'm suggesting making a way to get to that link from the main site (e.g. near the picture in the header--perhaps the image title?), without having to go to the wiki, look up the proper date's vote, and grab the URL.

Comment: @ahockley In addition to just having a large photo, something I like about the Flickr pages is reading the description.  I'm not suggesting that we put that on the site, but having the link go to some page somewhere with a larger size and/or a description would be nice.